# Capturar nuevos elementos en DOM a través de javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Estoy haciendo un script que incluye una especie de `eventListener`, el problema es que no puedo hacer que me consiga nuevos elementos que aparezcan en la página, ¿Es posible hacer esto?

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
texts.addEventListener('tipo', funcion);
```

La cosa es que en la página en cuestión, van llegando mensajes. Lo más fácil sería modificar el CSS pero la idea es tratar de hacerlo en un script, hay algún `eventListener` ¿que me permita detectar cuando llegan/aparecen nuevos elementos?

Lo más similar que he conseguido es un

```
texts.addEventListener('onClick', funcion);
```

Y es de lo más incómodo del mundo jeje

Algo que también he probado ha sido un `setInterval(funcion, 1000);` para que cada segundo repinte la página, pero es algo muy cutre.

Comment: Yo tiraría más por ponerle un [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) a una función que compruebe esos nuevos mensajes.

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres hacer: ¿quieres realizar una acción cuando un elemento se añada a la página? ¿o quieres añadir un controlador de evento a ese nuevo elemento (en plan evento delegado de jQuery)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro quiero realizar una acción cuando un elemento se añada a la página, por ejemplo un elemento que tenga class = "x", cada vez que un elemento se añada a la página, quiero hacer algo.

Comment: Mira el ejemplo que dejé, creo qué vás entender.

Comment: @sbrubes creo que lo pregunto es algo bastante claro, quiero realizar una función cada vez que un elemento se añada a la página. Por mucho que la edite, no se me ocurre como podría darle más claridad, si tienes alguna duda estaré encantado de responderte, pero a simple vista, no se me ocurre como podría mejorarla.

Answer (score 2):

Si no me equivoco, lo que buscas en un [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```
let observer = new MutationObserver( (mutationsList, observer) => {

    const element = document.querySelector(''); // Añade el selector del elemente que recibe mutaciones

    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {

        if (mutation.type == "childList") {

            // Logica que necesites
        }
    }
});

observer.observe(elemento, { "childList" : true });
```

En este caso, este script observa cambios en la lista de nodos, es decir si añades o quitas nodos al elemento que observas, entrara en la logica.

También puedes observar muchas mas propiedades, pero ten en cuenta, que necesita navegadores "modernos" y puede que no sea compatible con ciertos.

Comment: @sbrubes En SOes se valora mucho el dicho *Dale un pescado a un hombre y comerá un día, enséñale a pescar y comerá todos los días*. Este código es más genérico e incluye una descripción de qué se quiere hacer y como funciona. Tu respuesta incita a un C&P que solucionará el problema de hoy pero no a uno similar mañana. Esta respuesta **no** es un ejemplo, es una guía